# wkhtmltopdf rasterizes components of SVG with opacity

Tags: svg, centos7, wkhtmltopdf

I'm attempting to create a PDF file from SVG templates via wkhtmltopdf, but I keep running into the problem that any part of an SVG that includes transparency (opacity < 1) becomes rasterized.

This is on a CentOS 7 (Core) machine with wkhtmltopdf 0.12.5 (with patched qt). Along with a few hours of googling around and attempting a variety of solutions (e.g., rgba instead of opacity), the most relevant solution I've probably tried is using the bleeding-edge version of wkhtmltopdf, but that also fails.

Here's a sample HTML and SVG file to reproduce the issue:

*test.html*

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="test.svg">
</body>

</html>
```

*test.svg*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<svg
 version="1.1"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 x="0"
 y="0"
 width="100"
 height="100"
 viewBox="0 0 100 100"
 enable-background="new 0 0 100 100">

  <g>
    <line
     fill="none"
     stroke="#000000"
     stroke-miterlimit="10"
     opacity="0.25"
     x1="25"
     y1="30"
     x2="75"
     y2="60"/>

    <circle
     fill="#000000"
     cx="25"
     cy="30"
     opacity="1"
     r="5"/>

    <circle
     fill="#000000"
     cx="75"
     cy="60"
     opacity="0.5"
     r="5"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I then run `wkhtmltopdf test.html test.pdf` to get the PDF output.

The expected result is a PDF that looks just like the SVG (i.e., no rasterized components).